# Difference between ～として～ない and ～たりとも～ない

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words, word-usage

I would like to know if both expressions ～として～ない and ～たりとも～ない are completely interchangeable or if there is any difference between them.

According to several grammar websites, ～として～ない and ～たりとも～ない seem to have the same meaning (not even one) and be used in the same way.

However, in this web

https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3804

I've read that one difference between ～として～ない and ～たりとも～ない is that with ～として～ない you can say the expression 二人としていない (there is not another person like...), something not possible with ～たりとも～ない.

But then, searching for 「二人としていない」on Google, I found that 「二人としていない」is not a correct expression. The correct one would be 「二人といない」.

So, the sole difference between ～として～ない and ～たりとも～ない loses weight and in the end, I don't know if both expressions are the same or not.

If there is any difference in usage between ～として～ない and ～たりとも～ない, could you please give me an example where that difference can be noticed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`〜たりとも〜ない` is typically used to express the idea that even a small amount should not be allowed to break the continuity or completeness of something, or to deny the existence of such an amount.

> 一秒たりとも目が離せない。

> 一度たりとも嘘をついたことがない。

The usage of `〜として〜ない` is broader, and you can rephrase the above sentences with it without changing their meanings.

> 一秒として目が離せない。

> 一度として嘘をついたことがない。

In addition, it can also be used to express that even a single instance of something doesn’t do something or doesn’t meet some condition.

> 一人として彼を助けようとしない。

> 一つとして気に入るものがなかった。

These sentences would sound a bit weird if として was replaced with たりとも, at least to me.

An interrogative may precede the word for the single instance.

> 誰一人として彼を助けようとしない。

> 何一つとして気に入るものがなかった。

This seems to work only with として.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I understand better both structures. :)